# Angular: Kendo PDF Export is not bind the iframe content

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, angular10

Kendo PDF Export component
[Kendo pdf export code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10CqF.png)

Downloaded PDF without iframe content
[downloaded pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qInqH.png)

Do you have any idea about this issuses?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Code & response already added as image

Comment: Looks like iframe is not supported: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/limitations-browser-support